# Need regular expression for multilingual which allow only alphabets

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regular-language

I need regular expression which allow only alphabets of any language but doesn't allow special characters and numbers.
Right now i am using this express but it doesn't work in Arabic language

```
 ^(?=.{1,})[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,50}$
```

Comment: Why attempt to include all languages instead of just explicitly excluding special characters?

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 10):

> I need regular expression which allow only alphabets of any language but doesn't allow special characters and numbers.

You can use `\p{L}` which matches any kind of letter from any language.

```
^[\p{L}\s]{1,50}$
```

If you need to match `'` and dot `.` as well, just add them to the character class.

```
^[\p{L}\s'.]{1,50}$
```

Answer (score 1):

For Arabic use this

```
^[\u0621-\u064A\040]+$
```

it is working fine with me
only letters, no numbers